# Safari 6.1 hides inner div, when outer div has position:fixed and overflow:auto

Tags: html, css, safari, safari6

Safari seems to have changed their rendering of child objects outside their parents, in certain situations.

Setup:

- A parent (#outer) div with `position:fixed` and `overflow:auto`
- A child (#inner) div with `position:fixed` and positioned above or below parent

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/2tp9R/

I have only been able to reproduce this in safari 6.1. Firefox, Chrome and IE renders the child as safari used to do.

**Question:** How can this be worked around?

P.S. [Jeopardy!-ish question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround**

If `overflow:auto` is removed or `fixed` is changed to `absolute` the child is showed.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5kfbe/

This may not solve the problem in all situations though, e.g. when you need `overflow:auto` and `position:fixed` to be set on your parent div. Anyone got a better solution?